# Image Carousel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I create Image carousel slider like this? I tried but I get something wrong everytime.

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise for the carousel you can use both [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) or [carousel_pro](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_pro), and for the indicators in your image use [dots_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator).

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use flutter pub.
[carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)